# Automate "Find and Replace" Report generation

Tags: replace, ms-word, automation, find

I have to write 30+ memos related to stream crossings.  I have written the first memo, and it occurs to me that I could use it as a template for further memos.  All that would require revision in subsequent memos would be a few fields such as `Stream Name` `Crossing ID` and `Road Name`.

I would like to use a table with these field to automate the process of using them to replace placeholder values in multiple word documents.

Which programming languages or software packages could be used to complete this task?

Comment: You should refer to the site guidelines for asking questions on [help]. Your post covers too much ground - it's "too broad". Yes, it certainly can be done. You might want to take a look at Word's mail merge functionality, for starters - no programming necessary for that (and therefore a topic for an end-user site, such as SuperUser or Microsoft Answers).

Comment: I have read the guidelines in the past.  Thank you.  Is there a particular criteria that finds my question too broad?  This sort of question is useful for beginners who lack the vocabulary to pursue their goals.  Is there an edit that you would like to suggest?

Your answer about mail-merge is excellent, as it has given me a lead on a potential method for solving my problem.  You have given me the search terms that I need to go further with my own research on this topic.  Thank you. 

This task can also be done programmatically, in R for instance.  I am interested in other instances.

Comment: "too broad": It contains more than one question, to begin with. And it's not about a specific problem with a specific programming software or piece of code. That second question falls under "primarily opinion based" because there would certainly be more than one language or program / way to go about it.

Comment: Changed to one question.  It is a question that can be answered without opinion.  I think that this is a valuable question for beginners.  As I mentioned before, the first step is knowing what to search for.

Comment: ...and another reason for off-topic is requesting suggestions for software, tutorials, tools...